# multiple selects select the same option

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngfor

In my project, i have a table where various interventions are inserted based on previous selections. In case of more interventions, on the select if I go to select a value on the first intervention, it will also change on the second intervention. How can I make selections independent?

- **summary.html**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped" style="display: contents;">
  <caption></caption>
  <thead style="background:#ce5e59; color: white;">
    <tr>
      <th scope="colgroup">Interventions:</th>
      <th scope="colgroup">Surface Type:</th>
      <th scope="colgroup">Price:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of intervention; index as j">
      <tr>
        <td>{{element.int.code}}</td>

        <td>
          <select multiple [(ngModel)]="surface_type">
            <option selected disabled [value]="0">Select</option>
            <option [value]="1" [attr.disabled]="element.priceVis === 0 ? 'disabled' : null">Visible Surface</option>
            <option [value]="2" [attr.disabled]="element.pricePlast === 0 ? 'disabled' : null">Plastered Surface</option>
            <option [value]="3" [attr.disabled]="element.priceBoth === 0 ? 'disabled' : null">Both Surface</option>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td *ngIf="surface_type == 0"></td>
        <td *ngIf="surface_type == 1">{{element.priceVis}}€/{{element.unit}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="surface_type == 2">{{element.pricePlast}€/{{element.unit}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="surface_type == 3">{{element.priceBoth}}€/{{elemento.unit}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- **summary.ts**

```
intervention: Intervention[] = []
surface_type: number: 0
```

Comment: Can you make the snippet a [mcve]? Add your elements for example

Comment: replace all `[value]="X"` to `value="X"` and everything will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option [value]="1" [attr.disabled]="element.priceVis === 0 ? 'disabled' : null">Visible Surface</option>
```

`[]` as an attribute will be a one way binding of data with the variable that comes inside the `""`

so, for your case `[value]="1"` means you are assigning a variable `1` to the `value` attribute, and not the value `1` to `value` attribute.

for that to happen, you have to write as

```
value="1"
```

so finally, your code should look like

```
<option value="1" [attr.disabled]="element.priceVis === 0 ? 'disabled' : null">Visible Surface</option>
```

You will have to make the similar changes on all the `option` tags to make this work.

Please check the docs of [angular's property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) for more details.

Also

For the variable `surface_type` is the same for all the loops. so you will either have to change that to an array just like what [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10695495/erik) commented. or you will have to keep a variable `surface_type` on each of the object inisde `intervention` array. and replace every insance to

```
element.surface_type
```

Your interface `Intervention` should look something like this

```
interface Intervention {
   ... your objects ...
   surface_type: number|string

}
```

Comment: I commented above, that putting the [j] in surface_type gives me an error

Comment: try using it as key on the object inside your array as I suggested

Answer (score 1):

The `<select>` elements you generate all store their selected value in the `surface_type` variable. You could change `surface_type` into an array by changing the `ngModel` statement into: `[(ngModel)]="surface_type[j]"` Where I use the `j` index from your *ngFor.

Comment: ok, it makes sense, but it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot create property '0' on number '0'
    at SummaryComponent_ng_container_24_Template_select_ngModelChange_5_listener (summary.component.html:27)`, that would be the line with `<select [(ngModel)]="surface_type[j]">`

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Erik, you need to have your `ngModel` be an array:

`<select multiple [(ngModel)]="surface_types[j]">`

And secondly - you need to import **FormsModule** package into your Angular module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule      
    ]
```

I've created Sandbox on Stackblitz, you can inspect that:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsxgaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproduct-list%2Fproduct-list.component.html